# Laravel 5. Redirect with message after resetting password

Tags: laravel-5

How can I redirect a user to some route with message after resetting the password?
I've tried to override redirectTo method in `ResetPasswordController` but I got exception `Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected`

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    return redirect()->route('account')->with(['info_message','Password has been changed']);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redirectTo` method is used to get the route url i.e, it must be string.

In your case, You should override the `sendResetResponse` in your `ResetPasswordController`.

Add following lines in your `ResetPasswordController` :

```
public function sendResetResponse($response) {
    return redirect()->route('account')->with(['info_message','Password has been changed']);
}
```

Comment: If your issue is resolved then please accept the answer.

Comment: how can i use the message in the view?